# How would I render a List of Tabs in alphabetical order on a List page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list page that currently shows a list of Names. Is there a way in the Model that I can get it to show them in Alphabetical Order?

This is a property of my Model:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Using this in my View Model:

```
public IEnumerable<VerifiedSongTabMenuDataViewModel> Tenants { get; set; }
```

Comment: Just use a linq `.OrderBy()`

Comment: As you're using an `IEnumerable`, you can use the [OrderBy Linq extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: What you need is `Model.Tenants.OrderBy(x => x.Name)`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto that has worked. If you could put that as your answer that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have these viewmodels:

```
public class VerifiedSongTabMenuDataViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<VerifiedSongTabMenuDataViewModel> Tenants { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use LINQ `OrderBy` extension with `Name` property set for default ascending order (assumed you have `@model ViewModel`):

```
var orderByNameAscending = Model.Tenants.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
```